# Necromancing in Islam

Tags: sharia, history

From an Islamic perspective and belief is [necromancy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necromancy) possible?

If so, then is it permissible? And if *that* is so, then when in Islamic history was it practiced and why?

Answer (score 3):

As is known, Magic and everything having to do with it is **Haram** and so is divination , it is of the work of Shaytaan.

And whoever claims to have knowledge of the unseen or some hidden knowledge, or knowledge of future events is lying, talking about things of which they have no knowledge about, or relying on the Jinn for what they want.

> قُل لَّا يَعْلَمُ مَن فِي السَّمَاوَاتِ وَالْأَرْضِ الْغَيْبَ إِلَّا
>   اللَّهُ ۚ وَمَا يَشْعُرُونَ أَيَّانَ يُبْعَثُونَ
>
> Say, "None in the heavens and earth knows the unseen except Allah ,
>   and they do not perceive when they will be resurrected."

[سورة النمل آية 65(Surat Annamil)](http://quran.com/27/65)

The Prophet (Peace and blessings be upon him) said:

> لْمَلاَئِكَةُ تَتَحَدَّثُ فِي الْعَنَانِ ـ وَالْعَنَانُ الْغَمَامُ ـ
>   بِالأَمْرِ يَكُونُ فِي الأَرْضِ، فَتَسْمَعُ الشَّيَاطِينُ الْكَلِمَةَ،
>   فَتَقُرُّهَا فِي أُذُنِ الْكَاهِنِ، كَمَا تُقَرُّ الْقَارُورَةُ،
>   فَيَزِيدُونَ مَعَهَا مِائَةَ كَذِبَةٍ
>
> While the angels talk amidst the clouds about things that are going to
>   happen on earth, the devils hear a word of what they say and pour it
>   in the ears of a soothsayer as one pours something in a bottle, and
>   they add one hundred lies to that (one word)

[صحيح البخاري (Al Bukari)](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/59/97)